# How can i sync my repository with github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

simple example,

1)made a new project

```
rails new test_app
```

2) git commands

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git push origin master
```

ok finished!

now after this, if i look at github.com webpage gui.

it doesn't show my repository.

How can i set this to my github webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to create an repository on github. After that you need to create an ssh key with github for your pc. Befor you can push to the master branch you need to add the remote repository:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:yourrepo.git
```

Than push "origin" to the master branch.

Comment: in the rails tutorial book, it was like this step, and i was awkward what the ????

Comment: well.. you did not write that in your question. Please tell us excactly what you did

Comment: Thanks anyway, i was thinking there will be another way.

Comment: you're welcome but what do you mean by "another way"?